# How to Add/Update in Solr

Tags: java, curl, solr, solrj

I am trying to access solr using a java program and add/update records using it (which essentially creates a HttpUrlConnection and
Posts json data using curl).

While I should be able to receive response in my java program, I am getting a *File not found error*. Being a total newbie to this, the error doesnt seem to make sense to me.

Here is part of my code

```
 String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update?stream.body";
 URL obj = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type:", "application/json");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 String data ="{\"id\":\"978-0641723445\",\"apple_t\":\"set\":\"abc\"}";
 OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
 out.write(data);
 out.close();
 System.out.println(url+data);
 new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
 System.out.println("input"+conn.getInputStream());
 System.out.println(conn.getContent());
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any other approaches/inputs are welcome. Could somebody help to decipher the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HttpURLConnection Version**

```
try{    
    String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update/json?commit=true";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    String data ="[{\"id\":\"978-0641723445\",\"apple_t\":{\"set\":\"abc\"}}]";
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("input: "+conn.getInputStream());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Using [solrj](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj)**. I used version 5.3.0.

**Add New Document**

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg";
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
doc1.addField( "id", "new-document-id" );
Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
docs.add( doc1 );
client.add( docs );
client.commit();
client.close();
```

**Update Existing Document**

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg";
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
Map<String, String> operations = new HashMap<String, String>();
operations.put("set", "abc");
doc1.addField("id", "978-0641723445");
doc1.addField("apple_t", operations);
Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
docs.add( doc1 );
client.add( docs );
client.commit();
client.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I havent tried it yet. Is it possible to update a particular record(partial update) using the same methodology ?

Comment: I am getting the exception ClusterState says we are the leader (http://host:8983/solr/collection), but locally we don't think so. Request came from null

Comment: I updated again the answer. You can find both HttpURLConnection and Solrj solutions. I tested both the solutions on my solr instance and they worked correctly.

Comment: For the ClusterState exception, check if you have more then one running process and kill the older one.

Comment: You were right, that was the issue. Thanks once again

Answer (score -1):

tried to add solrInputDocument to solr sore using solrj but got "/update" added to URI..can't understand how to handle it.